# What is the maximum entry size?

Tags: ledger, shred

### Context

- The Solana blockchain grows in blocks (identified by the slot number)
- Each block is transmitted and stored (blockstore) using *data shreds*.
- Each *data shred* is a 1kB piece identified by (slot, shred index).
- A *data shred batch* (list of shreds with same slot covering a contiguous range of indicies) is reassembled into an *entry batch*.
- An *entry batch* contains multiple entries.
- An *entry* contains a PoH tick and a list of transactions (can be empty).
- Mainnet slot 0 as an entry batch with size > 1. IOW, a single data shred with multiple entries.
- Later mainnet slots usually have entry batches with size 1. IOW, a single entry that is split across multiple shreds.

[image: Entries vs shreds]

### Question

I'm desigining an archival solution for Solana blockchain data.
To understand the design better, I'm looking for info on entry and shred limitations.

What is the max limit, if any, or practical limit for:

- *Data shred count* per slot
- *Entry count* per data shred batch
- *Data shred batch size* in bytes
- *Entry size* in bytes

Comment: I don't think this is correct.
Afaik, there are 64 shreds per slot (32 data and 32 coding shreds).
This aligns with 64 ticks per slot.